# TcxLookUpComboBox entering Caps when I need lowercase

Tags: delphi, search, properties, devexpress, edit

I am using DevExpress `TcxLookUpComboBox` and it currently is set to `IsEditList`. The problem is if that list already contains a word with either upper or lower case I can't create a new word with the opposite case. For example I have the word "test" in the box but want to create "Test" I cant type a capital "T", only create new words with lowercases. I currently have `caseSensitiveSearch` set to false so that can't be it.

Comment: Have you checked the `charCase` property is not set to lowercase?

Comment: I have investigated this behaviour too, and based upon an answer by one of their engineers to a .net related question about the same behaviour, I believe it is by design and not something they are willing to change.

Comment: would there be a way to code around this design?

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q91634